# Не работает JS после переезда на новый хостинг

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

После переезда сайта с Shared хостинга с очень устаревшими конфигами(php 5.3.18 и тд) на выделенный сервер с ubuntu 18.04+ php5.6.40 перестали корректно работать js функции. Т.е например формы в админке не отправляют данные в БД, т.к. сама админка написана на JS. Если форму переправить на обычную ( с обычной отправкой через input type="submit" и без JS плагина текстового редактора) то форма отлично работает и отправляется.

В логах mysql, если сделана обычная форма все стандартно, обычные insert-ы, при включенных JS и отправки форму через него же insert-а в логах нет. Ощущение будто форма не сериализируется, но проблема в том, что JS не отрабатывает именно по всей админке. 
Собственно вопрос в следующем, есть ли в php какая-то настройка которая может блокировать js или как-то мешать ее работе?

P.S. На старом хостинге при этом всё отлично работает

Comment: Отладчик в руки и вперёд по шагам отслеживать поведение js и php, очевидно. Нужно не "ощущение", а точное понимание состояния js в нужный момент времени - точно сериализуется или точно не сериализуется

Comment: JS отрабатывает в браузере, к хостингу это не имеет ни какого отношения.

Comment: Я понимаю, что он отрабатывает в браузере. Почему он на старом сайте отрабатывает нормально, а на новом нет?.

Comment: а файлы js загружаются? Вы во вкладку Network смотрели?

Comment: файлы js загружаются корректно. Но почему-то на самом php файле при обновлении страницы вижу в Network статус canceled

Comment: $_POST выводит данные которые необходимы. Но не собирается строка запроса в mysql(при выводе через var_dump получаю NULL)